# SQL set variable as the result of a query in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure with a cursor and I need to store the quantity of a column into a variable.
SQL says that it cannot convert nvarchar into int
I have tried to use CONVERT, CAST and EXEC but couldn't make it work.
How can I solve this ?

```
DECLARE @FieldName nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @RequestCode Nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @ReqSQLQuantity nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Quantity int;

Select @ReqSQLQuantity = concat('select count(*) From (select distinct [', @FieldName , '] from [report_' , @RequestCode , ']) as number')
Set @Quantity = (@ReqSQLQuantity)
Select @Quantity
```

Comment: You can't run dynamic SQL like that, you need to use sp_executesql

Comment: also simplify that SQL Select Count(distinct MyFirstSQLFieldName) will do the job.

Comment: @JamesZ I found some stored procedure from another co-worker where he uses Exec(@requestSQL) and it works fine.

Comment: Yes you can also use exec, but sp_executesql is usually a better option since you can use variables with it without having to do string concatenation (but not for example for table names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another a bit safer option would be to use sp_executesql stored procedure something like this....

```
DECLARE @FieldName nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @RequestCode Nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @ReqSQLQuantity nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Quantity int, @tableName SYSNAME;

SET @tableName = N'report_' + @RequestCode

Select @ReqSQLQuantity = N'  select @Quantity = count(*) '
                        + N' From (select distinct ' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName)  
                        + N' from ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' ) as number'
Exec sp_executesql @ReqSQLQuantity
                  ,N'@Quantity INT OUTPUT'
                  ,@Quantity OUTPUT

Select @Quantity
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, why when I execute Exec sp_executesql, I have the correct result and then when I run select @Quantity, the value is null ?

Comment: are you sure you are using the `OUTPUT` clause ?

Comment: Yes I do use the OUTPUT keyword. I have copied/pasted your code into mine.

Comment: Ok I found my mistake, My tableName was report.report_table1 and it didn't work because the first report was the schema of the database and I had to add square bracket before the table name.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set @Quantite = (@ReqSQLQuantite)
```

This is not an evaluation, is an implicit conversion. From NVARCHAR to INT, and you are trying to convert a SQL query text into an INT, hence the error.

Also, you are assuming that *results* are the same as return values and can be assigned to variables. This is incorrect, SQL execution results are sent to the client. To capture a result, you **must** use a SELECT assign: `SELECT @value =...`. Trying to run `@variable = EXEC(...)` is *not* the same thing. Think at SELECT results the same way as a print in an app: a print sends some text to the console. If you run some pseudo-code like `x = print('foo')` then 'foo' was sent to the console, and x contains the value returned by print (whatever that is). Same with this pseudo-SQL, `@x = EXEC('SELECT foo')` will send `foo` to the client, and @x will some numeric value which is the value returned by EXEC (in a correct example one would have to use explicit `RETURN` statement to set it).

Overall, the code as posted has absolutely no need for capturing the value and returning it, it can simply execute the dynamic SQL and let the result be returned to client:

```
SET @sql = concat(N'SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT ... FROM ...)');
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```